# data not read in pandas, into runing epoch

Tags: python, pandas, split

I tried to run this code, this code generate epoch but why my data is not readable?

```
def test(learning_rate=0.1, training_epochs=15,
         n_hidden=500, delay=6, k=1):
 print ('... loading data')


data_path = "./data.csv" 
DataFrame = pd.read_csv(data_path)


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(261, 2))
msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8
train_X, train_y= df[msk]    
test_X, test_y= df[~msk]                
print ('... modeling')
rng = numpy.random.RandomState(123)


rbm = RBM(input=train_X, n_visible=28 * 28, n_hidden=500, numpy_rng=rng)

start_time = time.clock()

mean_cost_list = []

for epoch in range(training_epochs):
mean_cost = []
cost = rbm.get_cost_updates(lr=learning_rate, k=k)
print ('Training epoch %d, cost is ' % epoch, cost)

cost_plot(mean_cost_list)
end_time = time.clock()

pretraining_time = (end_time - start_time)

print(('Training took %f minutes' % (pretraining_time / 60.)))

return rbm
```

what causes unreadable data at run epoch?
I also tried to running without entering the dataframe, and epoch still running ...

Comment: I'm curious what you expect us to do when your script doesn't include the data that trigger the errors or even the import statements of the libraries that you're using.

Comment: Supposedly, I get the epoch results from that data, but even though I am replacing my data and deleting the dataframe, it has no effect. I am confused why when I am running to epoch the data is unreadable.

Comment: I can't run your example because I don't have your `data.csv` and I don't know where the `RBM` function comes from. If you want help for the SO community, you need to make a *Minimum, Complete, and Working Example* https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, the indentation of your `for` loop is incorrect.

Comment: the 'data' file, i get from 'close' stock price a weekly from 5 years.

Comment: how to overcome its loop?

RBM from the another file, rbm.py, maybe I'll add it in this post

Comment: Did you read about how to make an MCWE?